# J2me application showing error in some mobile

Tags: web-services, java-me, jar, midp, cldc

i have a j2me application with web service stub.
it worked in some mobiles.
but in some mobiles "Application Error" comes up.
i tried creating package making versions MIDP 2.0 and CLDC 1.0(made stub for CLDC 1.0 also)
still it is showing "Application Error"
if I create the package without stub the application works properly.

The stub was generated using "Sun Java Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 for CLDC"

can anyone help?

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {

        try {
        MobiService_Stub ms = new MobiService_Stub();
            resultBox.setString(ms.sendString( textbox.getString()));
        }catch (JAXRPCException cnfe){
            resultBox.setString("No connection found");
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            resultBox.setString(e.getMessage());
        }
            }
        }).start();
        resultBox.addCommand(cmd_Cancel);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have come up with "Application Error" messages when I try to run a Midlet that uses a JSR not available in that device. You should verify that the JSR or APIs you import are supported by your testing devices.